# RSA Encrytion throws an exception intermittently on JavaCard

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, javacard

I've written a program to encrypt `10` bytes random number using an RSA public key on my Java Card. The random number is generated each time that the card receives that APDU command, and as the related cipher object block size is 2048 bit in my applet, I append 242 bytes of `0x00` at the end of this `10` byte random number to make it `256` bytes length.

The problem is that sometimes the response is a Crypto Exception with `05` value. As you know and as JC API documents mentioned:

> **`0x05` = ILLEGAL_USE**
>
> public static final short ILLEGAL_USE
>
> This reason code is used to
>   indicate that the signature or cipher algorithm does not pad the
>   incoming message and the input message is not block aligned.

As the input length is fixed in my applet, I can't resolve my problem!

Here is the related part of my applet:

```
protected final void getEncChallenge(APDU apdu) {
        random.generateData(generatedChall, (short) 0, (short) 10);
        initAsymCipher(ENTITY_BOB, MODE_ENC);
        Util.arrayCopy(generatedChall, (short) 0, transientData, (short) 0, (short) 10);
        Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(transientData, (short) 10, (short) 246, (byte) 0x00);
        rsaCrypto(transientData, persistentData);
        apdu.setOutgoing();
        apdu.setOutgoingLength((short) 256);
        apdu.sendBytesLong(persistentData, (short) 0, (short) 256);
    }

protected final void rsaCrypto(byte[] inData, byte[] outData) {
    try{
        asymCipher.doFinal(inData, (short) 0, (short) 256, outData, (short) 0);
    }catch(CryptoException e){
        short reason = e.getReason();
        ISOException.throwIt((short)(0x6d00 | reason));
    }
}
```

And here is the response:

```
transientData ---> APDU Response
---------------------------------
80 ..(Eight Random Bytes).. BD ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> OK (i.e. 256 byte encrypted data)
EO ..(Eight Random Bytes).. 64 ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> 6D05
02 ..(Eight Random Bytes).. B3 ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> OK
CB ..(Eight Random Bytes).. 35 ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> 6D05
17 ..(Eight Random Bytes).. 97 ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> OK
0C ..(Eight Random Bytes).. 0C ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> OK
D3 ..(Eight Random Bytes).. 91 ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> 6D05
86 ..(Eight Random Bytes).. E2 ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> OK
C2 ..(Eight Random Bytes).. 23 ..(246 bytes of "0x00").. ---> 6D05
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with my applet?

Comment: What ALG_ do you use?

Comment: @vojta `asymCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are padding at the wrong side. RSA works on big endian encoded numbers up to the modulus size. The usual padding mechanisms (which are required for the usual RSA security) work by *left* padding, to a value strictly smaller than the modulus.

So basically your padded challenge is seen as a encoded number, and when converted, it sometimes is larger than the modulus. When that happens the RSA routine won't accept it.

Padding the zero bytes to the left should fix this. Alternatively you could make sure that the highest order bit of the challenge is masked to zero (`& 0x7F`).

Comment: Thank you dear Mr Bodewes. I'm a little confused. May I ask you please explain it a little more? I think as I Indicated that the algorithm is ALG_RSA_NOPAD, then the cipher must look at the challenge as a 256 byte data, not as a padded or encoded data. Right? So why there is any convertion? Does your answer mean that ALG_RSA_NOPAD, can not encrypt some forms of 256 bytes data?

Comment: Which convertion do you mean in  _... and when converted, it sometimes..._?

Comment: Yes, ALG_RSA_NOPAD cannot do that. The reason is simple; if you perform a modular operation on a higher number than the modulus then obviously the value will be treated as (in this case) `number - N`. So when you revert it you will get `number - N` as well instead of `number`. This is a fundamental issue with RSA. It of course depends on the challenge how big the decoded number really is. If it starts with `FF` hex then it is almost certainly larger than the modulus. If it starts with `7F` hex or lower then it *must* be smaller (as the highest bit of the modulus is always set) (try this).

Comment: Got it, thank you :). Is it mandatory for modulus to have the highest bit always set? Is it mandatory for private exponent too? I generated an 2048 bit length RSA keypair using Python to load them in my Java card. For one of them, the highest nibble was `0`! Does it make any problem? I mean, should I filter the off-card generated keypairs to those have highest bit = 1 in modulus and private exponent only?

Comment: Formodulus highest bit must be set. Private exponent can start with *any number* of leading zeros (each next one less likely of course).