# How to RSA Sign in java card?

Tags: rsa, sign, javacard

I have roughly spent about a week to write a 2048 RSA Sign algorithm for my java card.

There are too many problems like sending and receiving large amounts of bytes and so forth...

can anybody help to:

1) send and receive amounts of larger than 256 bytes to card

2) how to correctly `Sign` and `Verify` using java card?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think it is useful to warn you about [my fault in the past with RSA encryption padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059175/rsa-encrytion-throws-an-exception-intermittently-on-javacard).

Comment: @Abraham Thank you for you warning. do you have any idea about send/receive 2048 bytes and more and also how to implement RSA 2048 Sign in java card? I have found some pdf samples but they wew not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For signatures you can simply use the [`update` method of the `Signature` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html#update(byte[],%20short,%20short)). You should be able to send as much data as you want as long as you use a signature algorithm *that contains a hash algorithm*, such as [`ALG_RSA_SHA_256_PKCS1_PSS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html#ALG_RSA_SHA_256_PKCS1_PSS). For older card implementations use [`ALG_RSA_SHA_256_PKCS1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html#ALG_RSA_SHA_256_PKCS1). To send the data you can just use multiple commands instead of one or you could use *command chaining* as specified in IS 7816-4.

Alternatively you should be able to calculate (part of) a hash value offline and use [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html#setInitialDigest(byte[],%20short,%20short,%20byte[],%20short,%20short)), if it is present and implemented (it's relatively new, from 3.0.4 onwards).

The output size of 256 bytes should fit precisely in one response APDU for 99% of the implementations, so you should not have any issue with sending the response.