# Java BadPaddingException when verifying data signed on a JavaCard

Tags: java, encryption, padding, javacard, badpaddingexception

I'm signing some data on a JavaCard with a cipher, then outputting it into a text file, reading it into a java program and trying to verify it. I keep getting a BadPaddingException.

I'm signing it like so on my JavaCard applet:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1, false);
cipher.init(key.getPrivate(), Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
short sigCipherLength = cipher.doFinal(inputArray, inputOffset, inputLength, outputArray, outputOffset);
```

And verifying it like this (on my Java program):

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(inputArray);
```

When using Cipher.getInstance with "RSA" it defautls to RSA/ECB/RKPCS1Padding does it not? I'm stuck on how to get rid of the error.

Edit: to change encryption and decyrption to sign and verify, for clarity

Comment: Read the documentation so you can check what padding your decryption is expecting.  In crypto *everything* has to match exactly.

Comment: I'm confused in your wording: "*decrypting data signed*" - were the data **signed** or **encrypted** ? The usage of your key pair should be ** signing with private key** and **verifying with public key** or, for encryption, **encrypt with public key** and **decrypt with private key**. So what are you trying to do ??

Comment: You are not encrypting and decrypting. You are signing and verifying.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I'm trying to sign and verify a signature, I should have been clearer.

Comment: @rossum I have changed my code to specify exactly what padding is expected but am still getting the same BadPaddingException.

Comment: In that case thee might be a different fault so the padding is not decrypting correctly.  Perhaps try with `NoPadding` just to see what you are getting.

Comment: @rossum Unfortunately using `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);` throws up a 6F 00 error in javacard. Are there any other common causes it might be?

Comment: Look at the raw decrypted data.  There should be a recognisable padding at the end.  If yes then make sure that form of padding is expected.  If no, then you have a more general decryption problem and the padding is not decrypting properly along with everything else.

Comment: In the context of signing and encryption, different paddings are used. Encryption with the private key in the encryption context is not implemented uniformly regarding padding in the libraries (although this should actually be expected with Java and Java Card due to the relationship). Nevertheless, it might be useful to apply the [`Signature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html) class in the context of signing, s. also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42053092/9014097).

Comment: Shouldn't you be using _Signature_ rather than _Cipher_? Where do you specify the hash function?

Comment: @MichaelFehr: the Java crypto API was designed back in the 1990s when the mistake of treating RSA signing/verification as 'encrypting with the private key' and 'decrypting with the public key' was still common (see e.g. PKCS1v1 and PKCS7v1 -- NOT the later and improved CMS), and it does allow Cipher.init(ENCRYPT,private) and (DECRYPT,public) which actually do and reverse the last two steps of RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (pad 01FF...00 and modexp, but not the hash and ASN.1-encode DigestInfo steps).

Comment: LozCodes: make sure you are 'decrypting' (actually recovering) exactly the correct data -- not a bit changed, added or deleted -- and with the publickey matching the privatekey on the card. If you can add an example of the data and a (test!) key it might help diagnosing where the problem is.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I tookTopaco's advice and switched to using the signature class which seemed to fix the BadPaddingException, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [Which padding is used by javax.crypto.Cipher for RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033804/which-padding-is-used-by-javax-crypto-cipher-for-rsa). In short, do not rely on the default, it is best to fully qualify the cipher.

Comment: I have changed by code so that it specifies padding etc, but I am unfortunately getting the same exception still