# Java SignatureException when verifying RSA signature from JavaCard

Tags: java, exception, rsa, signature, javacard

I am getting the exception `SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 64 but was expecting 66` when verifying a signature.

I signed the data on a JavaCard:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_RSA_MD5_PKCS1, false);
KeyPair key = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA, (short)512);
key.genKeyPair();
signature.init(key.getPrivate(), Signature.MODE_SIGN);
signature.sign(dataToBeSigned, offsetOfData, lengthOfData, outputArray, outputoffset);
```

And I get the exception when I try to verify the signature in a separate Java program

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA");
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.update(dataToBeVerified);
boolean verified = signature.verify(signatureToBeVerified);
```

It seems that `signature.verify()` expects a signature of length 66, but the signature generated in the JavaCard applet is only 64 bytes long - I can't work out why this is.

Any help as to why the signature generated is too short, or why `signature.verify()` expects a longer signature would be greatly appreciated.

Edit to add extra information:

bigIntExp: 65537
bigIntMod:132308419546647374128240292677530807315542691147982039135818279043817855879255964354323446465801763768751278796804645533108455181966328171561226049067030642228779581871262216901734159959403381829035369468203140058451522951118452394154357893479460331007989274416039890367651223156420250223950749870305488385775751757831611317020777731747216787964833937998955451058221004606237913446120467690829592472183785281175197045866416933142014254513781922812566056256864142790656

Comment: With Java alone I cannot reproduce the problem. However, I do not have a Java Card environment. As mentioned in the other two questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66750260/9014097) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66765077/9014097), it would be helpful if you post test data (test key pair, data, signature). Btw, MD5 and a 512 bit key are insecure. Better use Sha256 and 2048 bit.

Comment: @Topaco I think my issue here is why the JavaCard generated signature is too short, so without a JavaCard environment you may not to be able to replicate it. I'm not sure how I can post the key pair data for you, apologies.

Comment: For a 512 bit key the signature should also be 512 bit = 64 byte. Therefore the length of the Java Card signature is correct. How long is a signature that you create in your Java environment?

Comment: @Topaco I've had a look and I'm not sure. I use `BigInteger bigIntExp = new BigInteger(expFromFile); BigInteger bigIntMod = new BigInteger(1, modFromFile); PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(bigIntMod, bigIntExp));` to generate the key, I'm not sure if that's where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I would also take the same `BigInteger` constructor for the public exponent as for the modulus (although that doesn't matter for 65537 = 0x010001 either). So it actually looks OK (assuming `modFromFile` and `expFromFile` contain the correct modulus and public exponent as `byte[]`).  Btw, by specifying the modulus, public and private exponent, either hex, base64 encoded or as `BigInteger`, you can also post test keys.

Comment: @Topaco I've edited the question to include the public modulus and exponent, that is generating a signature of length 66

Comment: The modulus has the size of the key, e.g. for a 512 bit key this would be 64 byte. The posted modulus has 194 byte = 1552 bit, [here](https://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php). So something is wrong. Typical key sizes are powers of two (512, 1024, 2048, 4096,... bit, with anything less than 2048 being insecure these days). Even if you post the correct modulus, the data is incomplete. The data (that has been signed), signature and private exponent are missing.

Comment: @Topaco+ and not only is the modulus the wrong size, it is even and has small factors -- an RSA modulus must be odd and not have small factors.